# Android smartphone to computer

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2010, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have an android smartphone and a laptop and I want to establish a bidirectional bluetooth link between them.

What I want is for my laptop to request taking pictures from the smartphone camera. After that, the command would tell the smartphone to send to the laptop the recently taken picture for further processing.

All the instructions shall be described inside a C++ program (all done inside Visual Studio).
My final intention with the pictures is to make some pattern recognition.

The question is: How can I achieve that without interfering with the smartphone?

With other words I'm in a room with a laptop, and in the other room is the smartphone. How can take pictures from the smartphone's camera via bluetooth, process them in my laptop, all without but a single command sent from a C++ program?